# Move visually selected text to end of line

Tags: vim

How to move visually selected text to end of line, which command or keys I should use?

e.g. `/text3<CR>` note that ** is a selected text, not part of it.

```
**text3** text1 text2
**text3** text1 text2
```

and move to this:

```
text1 text2 **text3**
text1 text2 **text3**
```

I tried: `:%s/\(text3\)\(.*\)/\2 \1/` any other ways to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically you can do it (after selecting your text visually like put the cursor on your word then hit <kbd>v</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>w</kbd>) with <kbd>d</kbd><kbd>$</kbd><kbd>p</kbd>. Any you can create a macro for it, I used to go with something like this in simillar cases: <kbd>q</kbd><kbd>q</kbd><kbd>/</kbd>`SEARCHTERM`<kbd>ENTER</kbd><kbd>v</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>w</kbd><kbd>d</kbd><kbd>$</kbd><kbd>p</kbd><kbd>j</kbd><kbd>0</kbd><kbd>q</kbd>. Now you can execute it as <kbd>NUMBER(s)</kbd><kbd>@</kbd><kbd>q</kbd>.

But as a more general solution:

```
:%s_\(YOUR_TEXT_TO_MOVE_TO_THE_EOL\)\(.*\)_\2\1
```

Should work just fine.

Comment: A little faster `diw$p`

Comment: You're right @hawk , the original question had talked about visually selecting text, that's why I had used `viw`.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `:global` command to select lines with the matching pattern and `:normal` to operate on those lines. For example:

```
:g/^text3 /norm! dt p d0$p
```

#### Explanation

```
:g/^text3 /<command>
```

Runs the specified `<command>` on all lines starting with text3 followed by a space. See `:help :global` for more information.

```
norm!
```

Executes the following commands in normal mode. See `:help :normal`.

```
dt p d0$p
```

Delete to the first space, paste that after said space, move forward one character and delete to the beginning of the line. Move to the end of the line and paste.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Damian Conway's dragvisuals.vim](https://github.com/shinokada/dragvisuals.vim)

After installation add the following (uncommented) to your .vimrc

```
runtime plugin/dragvisuals.vim

vmap  <expr>  <LEFT>   DVB_Drag('left')                     
vmap  <expr>  <RIGHT>  DVB_Drag('right')                    
vmap  <expr>  <DOWN>   DVB_Drag('down')                     
vmap  <expr>  <UP>     DVB_Drag('up')                       
vmap  <expr>  D        DVB_Duplicate()                      

" Remove any introduced trailing whitespace after moving... 
let g:DVB_TrimWS = 1
```

Or, if you use the arrow keys for normal motions, choose four 
other keys for block dragging. For example:

```
vmap  <expr>  h        DVB_Drag('left')                     
vmap  <expr>  l        DVB_Drag('right')                    
vmap  <expr>  j        DVB_Drag('down')                     
vmap  <expr>  k        DVB_Drag('up')
```

Or:

```
vmap  <expr>  <S-LEFT>   DVB_Drag('left')                   
vmap  <expr>  <S-RIGHT>  DVB_Drag('right')                  
vmap  <expr>  <S-DOWN>   DVB_Drag('down')                   
vmap  <expr>  <S-UP>     DVB_Drag('up')
```

Or even:

```
vmap  <expr>   <LEFT><LEFT>   DVB_Drag('left')              
vmap  <expr>  <RIGHT><RIGHT>  DVB_Drag('right')             
vmap  <expr>   <DOWN><DOWN>   DVB_Drag('down')              
vmap  <expr>     <UP><UP>     DVB_Drag('up')
```

### To use

Select with visual mode and move the block with h, l, j or k etc.

Answer (score 0):

The solutions involving `iw` will work if the text is `text3`, but they will fail on `two words`.

None of the methods involving `$p` will add a space, as your `:s` command does.  You could use `A <C-R>"<Esc>` instead.

If you want to do it on a single line, and the text is already selected in Visual mode, then `x$p` is pretty easy.

If the text is "selected" in the sense that you have just searched for it, and it is highlighted with the Search highlight group, and you want to make the change on a single line, then you could use `d/<C-R>//e<CR>$p`.  The `<C-R>/` will be replaced by the current search pattern, so you will get something like `d/text3/e<CR>$p`.

If you want to do it on all matching lines in the buffer, then a slight simplification of your solution is

```
:%s/\v(<C-R>/)(.*)/\2 \1
```

```
:help i_CTRL-R
:help c_CTRL-R
:help /\v
```